# django rest frame work: model fields on Django Rest Frame write error

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, view

I have a django app with following sections
models:

```
class Report(models.Model):
created_by_user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
planet_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
outage_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0) 
unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
responsible_group = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
alarm_num = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0) 
raised_alarm = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
event_desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
power_changes = models.FloatField(blank=True)
rel_asset = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
event_cause = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
maintenance_action = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
maintenance_cost = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
maintenance_mh = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
maintenance_dc = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
```

serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

created_by_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
class Meta:
    model=Report
    fields='__all__'
```

view:

```
class ReportCreateView(APIView):


def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    received_data=ReportSerializer(data=request.data, context = {"request": request})
    if received_data.is_valid():
        received_data.save()
        return Response(received_data.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(received_data.errors,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but when I send a report by Post method this error rise:
(1048, "Column 'start_time' cannot be null")

[image]

How I can fix it?I set blank=True for all fields but why it raise errors?

Comment: start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) in model help

Comment: right now its a required field for the database, change as above to make it a not required filed, after the above change, do makemigrtion and migrate